Does a nontrivial Hausdorff TVS always have nonzero continuous linear functionals
For the following,

Let $X$ be a vector space over $\mathbb{F}=\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{C}$, and $X^\#$ the algebraic dual, equipped with the topology of pointwise convergence $\tau_{pc}$. If a subspace $Y\subset X^\#$ separates points of $X$, then $Y$ is dense in $X^\#$.

I can prove this by constructing a net in $Y$ converging to an arbitrary $f\in X^\#$, as in here. But I'm wondering if, alternatively, I can also prove it by identifying the continuous annihilators of closure $\overline{Y}$, denoted as $\overline{Y}^\perp:=\left\{\delta\in \left(X^\#\right)^*:\overline{Y}\subset \text{Ker}(\delta)\right\}$, with the continuous dual space of quotient $X^\# /\overline{Y}$, denoted as $\left(X^\# /\overline{Y}\right)^*$. Since $X^\#$ is clearly Hausdorff and $\overline{Y}$ is closed, quotient space $X^\# /\overline{Y}$ is thus Hausdorff. Then the question becomes,

if $X^\# /\overline{Y}\neq \{0\}$, without using Hahan-Banach, can we alway be sure $\left(X^\# /\overline{Y}\right)^*\neq \{0\}$?

PS: We can freely use the fact that every continuous linear functional on $(X^\#, \tau_{pc})$ is an evaluation map $f\mapsto f(x)$, for some $x\in X$. Also, superscript $^\#$ denotes algebraic dual, while $^*$ denotes the cts dual.
Thanks in advance.
